# encryption in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

can this code be converted into an sql stored procedure

```
        string key = "test";

        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        hashmd5.Clear();

        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

`HASHBYTES` can do the first part.

For the second, look at `ENCRYPTBYKEY` which can encrypt using a Triple DES key.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331(v=sql.100).aspx for examples

Alternatively, you may want to consider a SQL CLR procedure.